# MySQL и tmpfs

Tags: tmpfs, mysql

Доброе время суток!

Решил посмотреть (в качестве эксперимента) как MySQL работает с tmpfs. Тем более, что под рукой есть несколько запросов, которые активно выполняют копирование во временные таблицы на диске (т.е. именно copy to tmp table on disk, а не простое copy to tmp table)

Поискал как это делается, нашел, например, [это](http://2bits.com/articles/reduce-your-servers-resource-usage-moving-mysql-temporary-directory-ram-disk.html), [это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7532307/skip-copying-to-tmp-table-on-disk-mysql) и что-то еще.

Сделал все как описано (строго следовал описанным шагам), но при перезапуске mysql вылетает ошибка:

```
./usr/sbin/mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/var/tmpfs/ibqTzRsu' (Errcode: 13)
141111 19:22:16  InnoDB: Error: unable to create temporary file; errno: 13
141111 19:22:16 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
141111 19:22:16 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
141111 19:22:16 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
141111 19:22:16 [ERROR] Aborting
```

При этом права указаны как 1777, владелец и группа - mysql.

Другим пользователем (не root`ом) в /var/tmpfs/ спокойно создаю файлики, а mysql почему-то на права ругается.

При этом сама папка примонтирована (mount сейчас выводит `tmpfs on /var/tmpfs type tmpfs (rw,size=2G)`, было также `tmpfs on /var/mysqltmp type tmpfs (rw,gid=113,uid=106,size=256M,nr_inodes=10k,mode=1777)`)

Если же верну в конфиге mysql дефолтные значение (tmpdir = /tmp), то запуск mysql проходит нормально.

Использую `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.35, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2`

В чем может быть причина, что я делаю не так?

Comment: Подозреваю защиту со стороный apparmor, которая блокирует доступ mysql к незадекларированным директориям

> nr_inodes=10k

Когда я по тупости скопировал эту строчку из инета для создания рамдиска, я очень быстро уперся в нехватку инодов.

Comment: @Etki, я пробовал добавить путь в `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld`, как сказано в комментарии к ответу по второй ссылке, но мне это не помогло (либо пропустил что-то еще).

Про `nr_inodes` - пока не важно, для начала бы запустить это дело, а тюнить потом уже можно будет. Тем более, что мне скорее всего не 256М понадобилось бы.